# Extracting the gz file using python ZIPFile

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-zipfile

I'm using Python 2.7. I have the following code

```
file = ZipFile("D:\\Project\\text.evt.gz")
```

Its giving the following error

> ```
> **"BadZipfile: File is not a zip file"**
> ```

While trying to extract the file manually,i am getting the following error

> ```
> **"Unexpected end of data"**
> ```

Is it possible to extract the `evt` file irrespective of this error in Python? Basically i want to extract the compressed `evt` file to a specific destination folder.

Comment: python -c "with open('D:\Project\text.evt.gz', 'rb') as f: print(f.read1(2))output is pk.

Answer (score 1):

The file extension "gz" suggests this is a gzip file, which is distinct from a zip file. Try the gzip module.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import gzip
import sys


with gzip.open('/Some/file/somewhere.gz', 'rb') as f:
    file_content = f.read()

for i in file_content:
    print(chr(i),file=sys.stdout, end='')
```

Though it might make more sense to look into a system call to **7zip** if you need this to be at all universal, and you don't have to manipulate the contents.

Comment: gzip does not offer the extract method to copy the extracted file to different location.Any idea how to copy the extracted evt file to different location using gzip?

Comment: @user3138864, the gzip module gives you a generic file-like object; you can use `shutil.copyfileobj()` with it to copy from that to any other file object on Python (without requiring enough memory to store the whole content in RAM, as the answer currently does).

Comment: @HackSaw, I'd advise against 7zip. It's not widely available on Linux, and security bugs are... not unheard of (particularly in the rar module -- sure, the OP isn't *intending* to use that module here, but that doesn't mean that it can't be selected via a crafted input file).

Comment: OP is on Windows, note the drive letter.

Comment: Sure. The security note remains pertinent.

Comment: Security notes aside, but not unloved, I also note the existence of p7zip in the Ubuntu archive.

Comment: still iam not able to read the gz content using the gzip.. Iam getting the following error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#24>", line 2, in <module>
    file_content = f.read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 261, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 303, in _read
    self._read_gzip_header()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\gzip.py", line 197, in _read_gzip_header
    raise IOError, 'Not a gzipped file'
IOError: Not a gzipped file.  Same file  iam able to open using Zipfile

Comment: Could you run this: python -c "with open('D:\Project\text.evt.gz', 'rb') as f: print(f.read1(2))"

Comment: I expect this as output: b'\x1f\x8b', thought other things are possible.

Comment: python -c "with open('D:\Project\text.evt.gz', 'rb') as f: print(f.read1(2)). output is pk

Comment: I think you don't have a gzip file, and you possibly don't have a compressed file at all. Looking at the "magic" sequences, a start of "pk" isn't among them. Maybe look at it with Notepad and see if it's just a text file?

Comment: Wait, is the output "pk" or "PK"? Try this: rename the file to text.evt.zip, and try your ZipFile version.